# Schedule class through apex code

Tags: scheduled-apex

I have to schedule a class through apex code. I am passing the cron exp. value from VF page and also passing the Batch/ schedule class name from same page into string variable. But for scheduling a class I have to pass 'class name' to the scheduling syntax. For that I have used below code but not working.

```
public pagereference Schedule() { 

    ApexClass classvar = [SELECT Id,name FROM ApexClass where name =:objecttoschedule]; 
    String sch = 'second minute hour * *  ?';

    system.schedule('test schedule', sch,  new classvar()); 
    return null;
}
```

By using this I am geting "Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: classvar at line 24 column 64"

I have tried with another option.

```
public pagereference Schedule() { 

    Type t = Type.forName(objecttoschedule);  

    String sch = 'second minute hour * *  ?'; 
    System.schedule(objecttoschedule, sch, (Schedulable)t.newInstance());

    return null;
}
```

By using this option I am able to save the class but at run time I am getting null value of 'Type t'.

Here 'objecttoschedule' is class name to schedule. Please help in this!

Comment: it is working fine for me. I would suggest debug ""objecttoschedule"" string if it has the correct value.

Comment: Yes, I am getting objecttoschedule value from Page.  But Type value Null "|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|**** Type :- null###### objecttoschedule :--BatchScheduleUpdate ". Please review this.

Comment: can you check once putting your class in the quotation mark. Type t = Type.forName('objecttoschedule');

Comment: I tried in workbench here I am getting value of 't                                             Type t = Type.forName('BatchScheduleUpdate');

system.debug('****:- '+t);  But not in the above code.

Comment: Does it work when you try to schedule apex via execute anonymous

Comment: are you calling the method through button ? then the value you are passsing it has some problem. You may trim the string and then try.